# ObjectAtIndex causes app to crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nslog

When I do an NSLog of the contents of my NSMutableArray, it returns :

```
(
    hat,
    hat
)
```

So why is it that when I do an NSLog like so `NSLog(@"%@", [pro.matches objectAtIndex:0]);` it crashes with the error: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'`

So strange

This is where I fill it:

```
[self.matches removeAllObjects];

         NSArray *JSONarray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil]];
         int i;

         for (i=0; i<[JSONarray count]; i++) {
             //[self.matches addObject:[JSONarray objectAtIndex:i]];
             [self.matches addObject:@"hat"];
         }
         //NSLog(@"boys with bo%@", [[matches objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"host"]);
         block();
         //JSON and add to matches.
     }
     }];
    block();
```

and this is where i call it:

```
[pro refreshMatchesWithCallback:^ 
    {
        //[self.tableView reloadData];
        NSLog(@"the count of a lifetime is %@", [pro.matches objectAtIndex:0]);
    }];
```

Comment: This is not enough code to see what is wrong. Could you provide some more code? For example where you create/fill the array?

Comment: When you print out the contents of the array as you posted, what is your `NSLog` call for that? And, as @dragon112 says, post more code so we can see your array being created.

Comment: @michaela in which class u do the NSlog plus tell me what is the senerio of the app r u using any sorta push pop, plus the thing i can think off is that the u must be setting the array to the pro object of the class, (but it all depands on the senerio of ur app)

Answer (score 1):

When you first log the contents it has nothing in due to the way completion blocks work, try this:

```
[pro refreshMatchesWithCallback:^ 
{
    //[self.tableView reloadData];
    if(pro.matches.count > 0) {
       NSLog(@"the count of a lifetime is %@", [pro.matches objectAtIndex:0]);
    }
}];
```

Hope this Helps!

Sam

Answer (score 0):

```
always prefer to use this approach

for(Object* obj in arra)
{
...

}
```

this will enter in loop if the counter is greater than 0. no check needed

Cheerz :P